# Facing issue on google pagespeed insights

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to know my website's page speed from google page-speed insights. But it showing question mark as result. I want to know about this question mark and its solution.
my website is developed in WordPress.

Comment: there will be an error message shown as well. You more than likely have a problem with the JavaScript on the site - care to share the link so I can have a look.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie please have a look on http://itoolsolution.co.uk and http://cool-itool.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommennd [Lighthouse Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/#devtools)

Simply follow the steps, and you can perform your first Audit without Page Speed Insights!

First step for your website is to serve images that are appropriately-sized to save cellular data and improve the load time.

For example: "07/besp_long1-1.png" which has a size of 1,761 kb can be served with a smaller size and in a next-gen format like .webp.

Answer (score 0):

The given URLs by you are showing following errors in Google Page Speed Insights:

**Field Data** - The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page.

**Origin Summary** - The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this origin.

It means that your website doesn't provide sufficient number of distinct samples that provide a representative, anonymized view of performance of the URL as per the [Documentation of Google page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#faq).

As an alternative I would recommend using [Lighthouse Tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) to avoid such issues.